# How to replace the middle of an Excel cell?

Tags: excel

I have a list of inventory for some of my products in Excel. I need to replace the middle of the cell with certain data.

Let's say each cell has data like:

```
Ronald RFD2322 Green 34 x 55 Large
```

But each cell is different.

One may be like the above, and the one below may be

```
Ronald RFD8827 Blue 21 x 25 Small
```

I need to replace the middle section, that looks like a model number (RFD2322), with a name, but some names are different. I need the cells to look like

```
Ronald Jimmy Green 34 x 55 Large
Ronald Sarah Blue 21 x 25 Small
```

If no one has an answer for that, how to at least replace the middle of the cell with a blank space so I can go back and fix it manually?

Comment: Will *all* of your products start with `RFD`? Or `RF`, or ...? How can we know that it's a product ID and not some text, a person's name, etc.?  (will it always have 7 characters? will it always start with R, and be 7 characters, etc. We just need a way to detect the pattern, then it should be pretty simple.)

Comment: Along with above, do you have a table somewhere that equates what should be replaced with what should replace it?

Comment: Yes, they all start with RFD, and have 4 digits after that, so each are 7 chararacters. Also, yes, I have the names in order that need to be put into the space where the model # is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will return the `Ronald Green 34 x 55 Large` assuming data is in cell `A1`

```
=LEFT(a1,FIND(" ",a1)-1)&MID(a1,FIND(" ",a1,FIND(" ",a1)+1),99)
```

Looking at your problem, it would more sense if the data to be substituted was in a column. E.g. if `Jimmy` is in `B1`

```
=LEFT(a1,FIND(" ",a1)-1)&B1&MID(a1,FIND(" ",a1,FIND(" ",a1)+1),99)
```

**NB** 99 is a random number, chosen as don't expect you'll have more than that many characters. It's silly as it's optional for `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions but required for `MID`.

Comment: Careful - this works if the second string is the RFD number. If it's somewhere else, it doesn't work.

Comment: Worked great, but the data returns as RonaldJimmy Green 34 x 55 Large, how to add a space in between the names?

Comment: @TayseNick - `=LEFT(a1,FIND(" ",a1)-1)&" "&MID(a1,FIND(" ",a1,FIND(" ",a1)+1),99)`

Comment: @BruceWayne Works great! I changed a small part of it since that formula gave me an extra space between Ronald and Jimmy. `=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)&" "&B1&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1),99)` Thanks! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with VBA, here's a solution using RegEx.

```
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As String
    ' Shamelessly lifted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/4650297
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String


    strPattern = "[R][F][D]...."

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = ""

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            simpleCellRegex = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

So, if cell A1 is "Ronald Blue RFD8827 21 x 25 Small", in B1, just do `=simpleCellRegex(A1)`.  Make sure the Regex reference is added, see [Step 1 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/4650297) to do that.

One benefit here, is that the RFD#### can be anywhere in the cell, and it'll get removed. You can probably get this with formulas too, but I am thinking they'd get pretty convoluted and tricky.

Comment: Thanks, your previous solution worked great. I am not familiar with VBA though. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @TayseNick - no worries. You'd just put that VBA into a macro. [Here's a page showing how](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/), then run `=simpleCellRange(a1)` in Excel, as if it were `=Sum()`, etc.